# Rails / ActiveRecord / SQL Return only 1 entry per user_id based on the highest priority

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have slightly complex relation going on my Rails application that I'm having a lot of trouble with.

For starters, there's a table that contains a list of roles which have an id and a priority. An example table looks like this

```
id  priority
1      5
2      4
5      3
6      2
7      1
```

Now there's also a join_table that likes user ids with role ids in order to keep track of which user is assigned which role. The complicated part is that a user can have many roles

```
user_id   role_id
   3          1
   3          2
   3          7
   4          1            
   4          5
   4          6
```

What I'm trying to get is to filter done the users_roles table to only 1 entry per user based on the role with the lowest priority.
So what I'm trying to end up with is:

```
user_id   role_id
   3          7
   4          6
```

The reason I would end up with this is due to the fact that roles 7 and 6 have the lowest priority.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I might have solved this my self. The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT user_id, role_id, min(roles.priority) 
FROM users_roles INNER JOIN roles 
ON users_roles.role_id = roles.id 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: `UserRole.joins(:role).select(:user_id, :role_id, 'min(roles.priority)').group(:user_id)`